# Ajax not passing data for login form to PHP process file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have PHP AJAX login script. Its nearly done, the way it works is that a user enters their information and then it takes them to the login page. My problem is that the input from the AJAX file is not being sent to the PHP file.

Its not giving me any errors btw.

This is the code:

HTML: `

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Your username">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="passWord" id="passWord" placeholder="Your password">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input type="button" onclick="submitRef()" class="form-control" value="Login">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Divvy"></div>

</form>`
```

This is the AJAX/Jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function submitRef(){

  if(userName == "" ){
    alert("You must enter something");
  }else{
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'adminLoginProcess.php',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      userName: $("#userName").val(),
      passWord: $("#passWord").val()
    },
    success: function (response) {
      window.location.href="adminLoginProcess.php";
    }
});
  }

}

</script>
```

This is the PHP

`

```
<?php
session_start();
include "conn.php";
$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$passWord = md5($_POST['passWord']);
echo $userName;
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";
echo $passWord;
$query = "SELECT uname, pass FROM Login WHERE uname = '$userName' AND pass = '$passWord'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($num_rows == 1){
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
    echo $userName;
    echo "logged in";
}else{
    echo "Wrong details";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

`

Comment: Why are you sending an ajax request to `adminLoginProcess.php` then on success, redirecting the user to `adminLoginProcess.php`? If you're redirecting to the same page, just use a form to submit the login info

Comment: I think your code got cut off somewhere. Can you show the first part of the HTML?

Comment: How do you know it's not being sent? When the ajax-call is done it just redirects the user to adminLoginProcess.php.

Comment: UPDATE: I Haven't gotten it to work. Thanks to your advice i made a redirect page in the ajax but its still not working, its just not passing the data to the PHP file.

Comment: Can you expain why you are using Ajax in the first place? It doesn't seem to make sense in this context. Why don't you use a normal form submit?

Comment: Well I want to add effects and validation to my website. It also is good to learn PHP, AJAX, Jquery at the same time since this is becoming the trend.

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'userName' is not defined within the scope of the function. It should be something like this. Try this instead and see if it helps.

> if($("#userName").val() == "" ){

Answer (score 0):

Change code like this:

```
<form id="main_form">
    <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Your username">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="passWord" id="passWord" placeholder="Your password">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input type="button"  id="form_submit_btn" class="form-control" value="Login">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Divvy"></div>

</form>
```

and js code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#form_submit_btn", function(e) {

 $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'adminLoginProcess.php',
    cache: false,
    data:  $("#main_form").serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
      window.location.href="adminLoginProcess.php";
    }
});

});
```

Comment: I tried that its still not passing the data to the other page.

Comment: can you check these: first check whether passing varibale through ajax: for that put this befor the ajax start `alert($("#main_form").serialize())`  if that alert not empty then there is no error with js, second in the php page put `print_r($_POST);`  and in the ajax success function `alert(response)`, check whether array is emty or not.